# c++ when using template<class T> error:.. is not a class

Tags: c++

I have written a class named `Queue`. When I try to build the project, I get a compile-time error.

The `.h` file:

```
template<class Queue_entry>
 class MyQueue {
     public:
    MyQueue();
    bool empty() const;
    // add entry in the tail of the queue
    Error_code append(Queue_entry &x);
    // throw the entry of the front
    Error_code serve();
    // get the front entry of the queue
    Error_code retrieve(Queue_entry &x) const;
 protected:
    Queue_entry entry[MAXQUEUE];
    int count;
    int front, rear;
};
```

It appears there's an error in the `.cpp` file:

> MyQueue.cpp:17:1: 'MyQueue' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

I don't know what's wrong, but when I change the template to

```
#define Queue_entry int
```

it can be run successfully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When asking my classmate I Know it should be

```
template <class Queue_entry>
MyQueue<Queue_entry>::MyQueue() {}
```

So this problem is solved. I should remember the format.

Comment: `class`mate haha
Thanks for the solution, you could mark this question as answered :)